# Games and programs installed on the device how can I separate lists

Tags: android

Using the following code retrieves the list of applications.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> appList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mIntent, 0);
```

From this list of games and programs you want to reserve. How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK there's no Android tags or codes to differentiate between games and normal apps. So you're out of luck.

Comment: Games are programs. ?

Comment: I know a program that can make this distinction: "clean master". There must be a solution to this problem, I think.

Comment: Does Clean Master get the list right? From what I thought, they just looked for the most common 'offenders' for leaving a lot of data behind. Eg `com.gameloft.*`  would be one and so on, I didn't think there was any information in the actual application to say what it is... Unless its location on the Play Store itself is relevant? (The store has a clear Apps and separate games section, so there must be SOME flag, somewhere) Good question btw, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK that supports such categorizations.

The category system depends upon the distribution channel -- the Play Store does not use the same set of categories as does the Amazon AppStore for Android. The categories also change over time. Some distribution channels, like directly downloading an APK from a Web site, have no categories at all. None of this has anything to do with the Android OS, which is why you will not be able to get this information from the OS.

Also, there will be many apps on the device that will not be associated with any distribution channel (e.g., pre-installed apps).

Comment: +1 yeah this was my thinking, but I wasn't sure how Google categorised the Play Store, but I'd guess it'd pretty manual, since there is no categories in the SDK.